# Convert PDO recordset to JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, pdo, recordset

Im using PHP and I need a way to convert an entire recordset to a JSON string.

While searching Stack Overflow I found this solution that works:

```
function recordSetToJson($mysql_result) {
  $rs = array();
  while($rs[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_result)) {
    // you don´t really need to do anything here.
  }
  return json_encode($rs);
}
```

The problem with this code is that I found that the function `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. Another thing is that im using PDO to connect to my database.

Given the circunstances above, what would be the best solution to convert a PDO recordset to JSON? I want it to work at later versions of PHP too.

Comment: What have you tried? Any tutorial? Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is simple.
Considering that the variable `$stmt` is your PDO recordset, you can convert it to JSON like this:

```
json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

For more info about the functions used in this piece of code:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score -1):

You should use something like that

somewhere previously

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM fruit WHERE name = ?");
$stmt->execute(array("Apple"));
....


function recordSetToJson($stmt) {
  $json_result = array();
  while($tmp = $stmt->fetch() ) {
       $json_result[] = $tmp;
  }
  return json_encode($json_result);
}
```

But final solution will be totally depends form too many factors.

Comment: array("Apple")) won't do anything if I'm not mistaken. But I get ya point, like I described in my comment.

Comment: @Jonast92 sorry, what do you mean ?

Comment: execute(array(":name" => "Apple")); would do something.

Comment: Your solution works, but there's still a little problem. For each column on the row it will create 2 properties with the same value. For example: {"name":"john","0":john}